# How can i start my application as "Run as Administrator" forcefully?

Tags: wpf, application-settings, prism-4

In my application,I am writing some values in application settings file.
As i am working with prism I have some module and one shell project.
After installing setup

Case: 1

When i have not set compatibility mode as "Run as Administrator".
Running application i am able write application settings for all modules but unable to write for main shell project.

Case: 2

When i have set compatibility mode as "Run as Administrator".
Now i am  able write settings for all.

Required Solution:

I want to set my application compatibility mode as administrator forcefully but don't know how to do it?

Comment: "Required Solution" -> there's another, imo better, and that is to _not_ write in the app settings file but in a user config file. Place it in ProgramData or so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add an app.manifest to your project.
In there, under trustInfo --> security --> requestedPrivileges node, uncomment this line:

`<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`

Then you're good to go.

Comment: when my application fetching some dll form Programfies/Company/My applicationat run time it gives me error as The Just-In-Time debugger was launched without necessary security permission

Comment: it was my application dll problem not manifest problem.. and your suggestion works for me. Thanx...

Comment: Correction, the manifest file should not be added to the solution, but to the project. (Right-click project in Solution Explorer and Add new item...)